Why ESLint and Prettier stopped working in a VScode?
I have a Vite+React project and everything was working fine. I haven't opened it for a month and now when I do open it, I see an error like this in all the components. Also, Prettier doesn't fix or highlight any error I make. I would like to know what caused this problem because all the settings in VS Code seem to be fine.

My files looks like this:
{....
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc -b && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts,.tsx .",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.ts,.tsx .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^43.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^9.0.0",
    "@dnd-kit/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@dnd-kit/modifiers": "^7.0.0",
    "@dnd-kit/sortable": "^8.0.0",
    "antd": "^5.20.2",
    "ckeditor5": "^43.0.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^8.57.1",
    "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/eslint": "^9.6.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^8.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^8.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "28.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "5.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.2",
    "globals": "^15.10.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "sass": "^1.77.8",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.8.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.2",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^5.0.1"
  }
}

module.exports = {
  env: {
    node: true,
    browser: true,
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  extends: ['airbnb', 'prettier', "eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/jsx-runtime"],
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'jest', 'react', 'import', 'react-hooks', 'prettier',],
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    // Padding rules
    'no-multiple-empty-lines': [2, { max: 1 }],
    'padding-line-between-statements': [
      2,
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: ['if', 'return'] },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: 'block-like', next: '*' },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: ['const', 'let'], next: '*' },
      { blankLine: 'any', prev: ['const', 'let'], next: ['const', 'let'] },
    ],
    'lines-between-class-members': [2, 'always', { exceptAfterSingleLine: true }],
    // Import rules
    // 'no-restricted-imports': ['error', 'echarts', 'echarts-for-react'],
    'import/no-named-as-default': 0,
    'import/no-named-as-default-member': 0,
    'import/prefer-default-export': 0,
    'import/extensions': [
      2,
      'ignorePackages',
      {
        js: 'never',
        jsx: 'never',
        ts: 'never',
        tsx: 'never',
      },
    ],
    // OFF rule after /common moved in com
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 0,
    // Prettier rules
    'prettier/prettier': [
      2,
      {
        trailingComma: 'all',
        singleQuote: true,
        printWidth: 120,
        endOfLine: 'auto',
        useTabs: false,
        arrowParens: 'always',
        bracketSpacing: true,
        bracketSameLine: false,
        semi: true,
        tabWidth: 2,
        importOrderSeparation: true,
        importOrder: [
          '^react(.*)',
          '<THIRD_PARTY_MODULES>',
          '^(helpers|hooks|enum)/(.*)',
          '^styles/(.*)',
          '^icons/(?!logos)(.*)',
          '^./(components|icons)/(.*)',
          '^[./].*(?<!\\.(c|le|sc)ss)$',
          '\\.(c|le|sc)ss$',
        ],
        importOrderSortSpecifiers: true,
      },
    ],
    // Length rules
    'max-len': [
      2,
      {
        code: 120,
        tabWidth: 2,
        comments: 120,
        ignoreComments: false,
        ignoreTrailingComments: true,
        ignoreUrls: true,
        ignoreStrings: true,
        ignoreTemplateLiterals: true,
        ignoreRegExpLiterals: true,
      },
    ],
    // React rules
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx'] }],
    'react/jsx-uses-react': "off",
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': "off",
    'react/jsx-no-bind': [
      2,
      {
        ignoreDOMComponents: true,
        ignoreRefs: false,
        allowArrowFunctions: true,
        allowFunctions: false,
        allowBind: false,
      },
    ],
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': [0],
    'react/require-default-props': [0],
    'react/state-in-constructor': [0],
    'react/destructuring-assignment': [0],
    'react/function-component-definition': [0],
    'react/no-unknown-property': ['error', { ignore: ['contact-form-role'] }],
    'react/no-danger': 0,
    // JSX a11y rules
    'jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': [
      0,
      {
        components: ['a'],
        specialLink: ['href'],
      },
    ],
    'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': [0],
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': [0],
    // Redux toolkit rules
    'no-param-reassign': ['error', { props: false }],
    // Common rules
    'no-shadow': 0,
    'no-use-before-define': 0,
    'no-unused-vars': 0,
    'no-undef': 0,
    'no-bitwise': 0,
    'consistent-return': 0,
    'no-plusplus': 0,
    'no-restricted-globals': [0, 'event', 'pageYOffset'],
    'no-template-curly-in-string': 0,
    'no-control-regex': 0,
    'func-names': ['error', 'never'],
    // Disable camelcase as we use properties from drupal in snake case
    camelcase: 'off',
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['.test.js', '.test.jsx'],
      rules: {
        'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 0,
      },
    },
  ],
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        moduleDirectory: ['node_modules', 'src/'],
      },
    },
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
      pragma: 'React', // Add this line
    },
  },
};

{
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "bracketSameLine": false,
  "printWidth": 120,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "useTabs": false,
  "plugins": ["@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports"],
  "importOrderSeparation": true,
  "importOrder": [
    "^react(.*)",
    "<THIRD_PARTY_MODULES>",
    "^(helpers|hooks|enum)/(.*)",
    "^styles/(.*)",
    "^icons/(?!logos)(.*)",
    "^./(components|icons)/(.*)",
    "^[./].*(?<!\\.(c|le|sc)ss)$",
    "\\.(c|le|sc)ss$"
  ],
  "importOrderSortSpecifiers": true
}

tsconfig.app.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", ".eslintrc.cjs"]
}

tsconfig.node.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", ".eslintrc.cjs"]
}

Settings have not been changed. I have already tried to reinstall all packages + VS Code extensions.
UPDATE
When I do Ctrl + Shif + p -> Format document with -> Prettier - Code formatter It fix all my errors

Can you please add your tsconfig.json file?

Of course. Done

"When I do Ctrl + Shif + p -> Format document with -> Prettier - Code formatter It fix all my errors" Are you still facing errors related to this question or have you solved them? If you have solved it you should remove all contents under UPDATE and answer your own question instead.

I still have this issue

What happens when you add import React from "react"; to the top of the file. It is generally recommend to do so in React

I already have it in my main App.tsx file. There is no need to add it in every file

Do you have format on save and default format configured with the right path?
